# I/O request flow, are APCs used for blocking requests as well?

Tags: windows, io, driver, irp

I'm trying to fully understand the I/O request flow that happens when e.g. ReadFile is invoked. I'm aware of how the I/O-Manager creates an IRP and passes it down the driver-stack. Once the data has been retrieved from the device, an interrupt occurs, the driver ISR is executed to schedule a DCP. What happens between the DCP and the application buffer being filled with data?

Comment: The details depend on the specific drivers in the stack, I believe.  But as I understand it, a blocking call is implemented as an asynchronous call followed by a wait operation, i.e., the I/O manager sets an event to indicate that the I/O is completed.

Comment: To clarify, that's a *conventional* asynchronous call - one using an event - rather than an APC-based asynchronous call.  And of course this is an implementation detail, subject to change.